# Fedora 24: no build.include / try to generate autoconf.h

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, rpm, build

Trying to build a package which needs autoconf.h

So i installed kernel-devel, ran make oldconfig and make prepare
but unfortunalety it did not work

Couldn't find any solution in the web, any ideas?

It seems like i am missing the build.include file

```
[root@linux 4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64]# make oldconfig
scripts/kconfig/conf  --oldconfig Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#

[root@linux 4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64]# make prepare
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  DESCEND  objtool
/usr/src/kernels/4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.build:32: /usr/src/kernels/4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64/tools/build/Build.include: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/kernels/4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64/tools/build/Build.include'.  Stop.
Makefile:36: recipe for target '/usr/src/kernels/4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64/tools/objtool/fixdep-in.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/kernels/4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64/tools/objtool/fixdep-in.o] Error 2
/usr/src/kernels/4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.include:7: recipe for target 'fixdep' failed
make[2]: *** [fixdep] Error 2
Makefile:59: recipe for target 'objtool' failed
make[1]: *** [objtool] Error 2
Makefile:1554: recipe for target 'tools/objtool' failed
make: *** [tools/objtool] Error 2

[root@linux 4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64]# pwd
/usr/src/kernels/4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64

[root@linux 4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64]# uname -r
4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64

[root@linux 4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64]# rpm -q kernel-devel
kernel-devel-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
kernel-devel-4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64

[root@linux 4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64]# rpm -q kernel-headers
kernel-headers-4.6.3-300.fc24.x86_64
```

Comment: Just to be clear: your package needs the _kernel's_ `autoconf.h`.

Comment: Hi mattdm, exactly, it needs the kernel's autoconf.h

Comment: Did you get any resolution on this issue?